# jQuery event contextmenu triggers underlaying div

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, jquery

looking at this event (being bind on 2 divs overlapping each other, look at the jsfiddle)

```
.on('contextmenu', function() { ... });
```

1. Why do *both* divs being triggered?
2. How can I detect this and or stop the underlaying div from triggering?

**DEMO**: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Rftp/)

Thanks for any information!

Comment: @A. Wolff - you are right. Deleted the answer. `return false` hides the default behaviour as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On nested element,  you need to stop event bubbling:

```
$('#div2').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#log').append('<p>div2 triggered contextmenu!</p>');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Rftp/4/)

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Rftp/6/)

```
$('#div1,#div2').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#log').append('<p>' + e.target.id + ' triggered contextmenu!</p>');
});
```

[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

[event.stopPropagation/](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: so where is the context menu? ;)

Comment: Since A. Wolff was a little bit quicker I upvoted your contribution, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent event from propogating, try this code:

```
$('#div1').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()){
    $('#log').append('<p>div1 triggered contextmenu!</p>');
    e.preventDefault();
}
});

$('#div2').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()){
    $('#log').append('<p>div2 triggered contextmenu!</p>');
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```